# allow tab and other keys in input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Below is my javascript code which restrict the user for following:

1) only allow numeric and upto two decimal points.

It also restrict the user for tab, backspace , delete, left and right arrow keys.

I tried by adding condition event.which != 8/9/37/38 but not succeed.

Below is the code:

```
$('#txtprice').keypress(function (event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();

    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

can any one please correct me here.

`EDITED:` Modified as below but not work.

```
    $('#txtprice').keypress(function (event) {

                if (event.which == 8 || event.which == 9 || event.which == 37 || event.which == 38) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }

                if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }

                var text = $(this).val();

                if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) && (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try: `if (event.which == 8 || event.which == 9 || event.which == 37 || event.which == 38) { event.preventDefault();`

Comment: can any one please guide.

Comment: this is just allowing other key as well.

Comment: As i see it, the logic should be inside .onkeyup , besides, pay attention that this event is thrown beforce the actual key is shown on the textbox.Therfore, u deny any event of any key besides numbers and so it cancles thier effect (adding key or doing a space, etc..)

Comment: Modified but, not working.. please see updated quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

You simply just have to allow what you want, not determine what you don't want. This is easy by determining if the `keyCode` is a period (190) or in between 48 and 57.

```
function validateNum(e) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("txtprice");
    if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 || e.keyCode == 190) {
        var txt = elem.value;
        if (e.keyCode == 190 && txt.match(new RegExp('\\.','g')).length > 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();   
    }
}
```

Here is a working js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e72uqvbv/

UPDATE: I miss understood the period situation request, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Its not allowing backslash, delete chars also, not restricing till two digits decimal only (optionallY).

Comment: @dhavalsoni I am not understanding what you want at all then